# How to sort associative arrays by value of a given key and maintain key in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Given this array

```
$inventory = array(
    "sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf1"=>array("type"=>"fruit", "price"=>3.50),
    "sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf2"=>array("type"=>"milk", "price"=>2.90),
    "sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf3"=>array("type"=>"pork", "price"=>5.43)
);
```

I want output like below

```
$inventory = array(
    "sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf3"=>array("type"=>"pork", "price"=>5.43),
    "sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf1"=>array("type"=>"fruit", "price"=>3.50),
    "sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf2"=>array("type"=>"milk", "price"=>2.90)  
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$inventory = array(
  array("sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf1"=>array("type"=>"fruit", "price"=>3.50)),
  array("sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf2"=>array("type"=>"milk", "price"=>2.90)),
  array("sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf3"=>array("type"=>"pork", "price"=>5.43))
);

usort($inventory, function($a, $b) {
  foreach ($a as $a);
  foreach ($b as $b);
  if ($a['price'] == $b['price']) return 0;
  return ($a['price'] < $b['price']) ? 1 : -1;
});

print_r($inventory);
```

Comment: Can you give me output of Array
(
    [sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf1] => Array
        (
            [type] => fruit
            [price] => 3.5
        )

    [sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf2] => Array
        (
            [type] => milk
            [price] => 2.9
        )

    [sdfsdfsdsx65fsdf3] => Array
        (
            [type] => pork
            [price] => 5.43
        )

)

Comment: Yes, Your output is write but I have edit the question please check once and please give me a output